# Conflicting CSS code

Tags: html, css, image, slider

so I've been having a huge problem with trying to insert an image slider to my website at the moment, primarily that the nav bar CSS code is conflicting with the code for the slider. I imagine that there is a way to separate different CSS codes but I haven't found it yet.

In keeping the code as simple as possible to break down, here is the CSS I'm using.

```
<style type="text/css">
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
 div {position:relative;height:3.2em;background:#FFFF99;border-top:2px
      solid;border-bottom:2px solid;margin:0 0 30px;}
   #nav {position:absolute;left:50%;top:0;margin-left:-380px;
      height:3.2em;width:760px;list-style:none;}
   #nav li {float:left;}
   #nav a {display:block;text-align:center;color:#000;height:3.2em;
      width:120px;line-height:3.2em;text-decoration:none; margin-left:
      -2px;font-weight:bold;border-left:2px solid #000;border-right:2px solid #000;}
   #nav a:hover,
   #nav a:focus {background:#5E9BD9;color:#fff;}
   #nav .active {background-color: #5E9BD9;}
</style>
```

And here is the HTML

```
<div>
<ul id="nav">
 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
 <li><a href="About.html">About us</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Booking</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Register</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Please can I have help with splitting large groups of CSS code (I can do with singular lines but not for a large block like I have here)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Where's the code for the slider?

Comment: Why would you use `nav` as your slider ID when you already have a navigation ID of `nav`?

Comment: @JosephMarikle Where does the OP say that the slider ID is `nav`?

Comment: You need to supply the CSS and the JS/JQ for the image slider plugin (I'm assuming it's a plugin). You should create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Comment: @zer00ne Absolutely nowhere.  It's an assumption with the hope that OP will respond and clarify.  Comments are intended to generate that kind of communication between OP and the developers.  If I knew for certain that the OP was using the same IDs, I could make an answer rather than just a comment.

Comment: @JosephMarikle I'm assuming the OP thinks it's a simple set and forget kind of Q&A.

Comment: @zer00ne That's very likely to be true.  We can always hope that the OP is communicative, but that's not always the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you give you slider div a unique id e.g

```
<div id="sliderwrapper">
```

then code your css in the following way

```
#sliderwrapper {
  background-color: #ddd;
  ... etc etc

}
#sliderwrapper > div {
  //this applies to divs that are DIRECTLY below the slider object
  color: brown;
  ... etc
}
#sliderwrapper div {
  //Any div at any level below the slider, not just directly below
}

#sliderwrapper .classnameyoucreated {
   //classes that exist below the slider at any level

}
```

you can also specify custom attributes if your using html5. e.g.

```
<div id="sliderwrapper"><a class="classnameyoucreated" data-anythingyouwanttowriteherewillwork="value"></div>

#sliderwrapper > a.classnameyoucreated[data-anythingyouwanttowriteherewillwork=value] {
  background-color: red;
  ... etc etc
  //This is ultra specific and almost impossible to inadvertently override in another css block - specificity is the key here.
}
```

Because you've specified #nav in your CSS as long as #sliderwrapper is not a child of that tag you shouldn't have a conflict.  If you do have a conflict there are some rules to remember.

1. The last specifier read by the browser is the priority
2. The most specifically defined specifier will trump a more ambiguous specifier
3. you can always override any value by adding !important to the end - but this is lazy and is bad practice when its over used.

You can also consider using .less files to enhance the syntax a bit and organize your code.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like its an issue with specificity, hard to say though without seeing the code for the slider.  As long as the nav bar and slider have no classes that overlap, there shouldn't be any issues.

Perhaps adding `class="slider-[sometext]"` to all slider elements and styling from there would solve your 'conflict' issues?

Comment: Yes, share the code for the slider and we can start from there.

Answer (score -1):

you have to use different ID-s.